# Меняется размер шрифта тайтла при смене ориентации

Tags: android, шрифты

В манифесте для всех активити запрещено пересоздание. Альтернативных активити для ландшафтной ориентации нет. Если повернуть устройство и вызвать какое-либо активити - размер шрифта заголовка становится значительно мельче. Причем этот размер не меняется, даже если вернуть приложение к портретной ориентации. С другой стороны, размер шрифта заголовка окна, созданного в портретной ориентации, при повороте экрана не уменьшается. Почему уменьшается размер шрифта у окна, созданного в ландшафтной ориентации?

Comment: А у вас `ActionBar` или `Toolbar`?

Comment: В приложении Toolbar

Comment: Попробуйте задать ему атрибут `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: Я понял вашу мысль, речь не о самом тулбаре,  а о размере шрифта заголовка. Тем не менее, попробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В тэг `Toolbar`

```
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
```

В `styles.xml`

```
<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```